# Nexus 5 crash: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon - SurfaceTexture.finalize()

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, nexus-5

We're seeing a peculiar issue when attempting to re-encode videos, and it only seems to happen on the Nexus 5. We use MediaCodec to compress and re-encode videos clientside, and sometimes when the task is running on a Nexus 5 we get the following crash:

```
05-15 16:25:15.023 E/AndroidRuntime( 4716): FATAL EXCEPTION: FinalizerWatchdogDaemon
05-15 16:25:15.023 E/AndroidRuntime( 4716): java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.finalize() timed out after 10 seconds
05-15 16:25:15.023 E/AndroidRuntime( 4716):     at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.nativeFinalize(Native Method)
05-15 16:25:15.023 E/AndroidRuntime( 4716):     at android.graphics.SurfaceTexture.finalize(SurfaceTexture.java:353)
05-15 16:25:15.023 E/AndroidRuntime( 4716):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.doFinalize(Daemons.java:190)
05-15 16:25:15.023 E/AndroidRuntime( 4716):     at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:173)
05-15 16:25:15.023 E/AndroidRuntime( 4716):     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Our code is relatively similar to to bigflake's DecodeEditEncodeTest (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/DecodeEditEncodeTest.java), and we are also using their InputSurface, OutputSurface, and TextureRender classes (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/cts/+/jb-mr2-release/tests/tests/media/src/android/media/cts/). I am guessing that the issue occurs somewhere in OutputSurface or TextureRender as they're the classes that actually manipulate a surface texture.

The only reliable repro steps we can come up with is that it seems to happen somewhat randomly when several videos are queued to be re-encoded, even though the encoder only handles one video at a time.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

The SurfaceTexture finalizer is hanging for some reason.  The VM detects the stuck thread and throws an exception.

The SurfaceTexture finalizer is [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.java#351), though it just calls `nativeFinalize()`, which you can see [here](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/lollipop-release/core/jni/android/graphics/SurfaceTexture.cpp#272).  There isn't much going on -- just zeroing out fields and adjusting reference counts -- so it's unclear from the "Lollipop" sources why this would hang.  "KitKat" and "Lollipop-mr1" look about the same.

What version of Android is running on that device?

Comment: Both devices we see this on are running 5.0, both Nexus 5s. I believe I've found a potential fix; in the `release()` call of OutputSurface, the line `mSurfaceTexture.release()` was commented out. Uncommenting this seems to have fixed the issue,  and it makes sense to release the SurfaceTexture here. Now I'm just curious/cautious about why it was commented out in the first place.

Comment: Could be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30172529/when-is-a-textureviews-consumer-side-closed, though the accepted answer there is specifically about the Camera.  Something is not quite right in the platform if an explicit release of the SurfaceTexture is necessary.

Comment: Any ideas why we observed this only on the N5 and not any other devices running Lollipop?

Comment: I would guess it's a race that happens to lose on the N5. I don't really understand why it's getting stuck, so I don't have much to go on. The next step would be to get a native stack trace to see where exactly it's at; this used to be emitted automatically by Dalvik when finalizers got stuck, but I think that feature was removed (grumble grumble). You might be able to get this by having the app catch the exception with a global default handler and then send itself a couple of SIGTERMs to get a dump in logcat. (I haven't done this, but I think it'll work.)